# Can I get a visa to the US if I'm on sabbatical leave?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I want to renew my visa to visit the US. The problem is that I'm currently not working because I'm on a "sabbatical" year. I've previously traveled at least 5 times to the US and have had a 10 year visa which expired 5 months ago.

Am I likely to have mi renewal denied because of my current job situation?

Comment: Are you still employed, and can you get a letter from your employer confirm that you'll be reinstated at the end of your sabbatical?

Comment: You're not required to have a job in order to get a US B1/B2 visa. You _are_ required to demonstrate significant ties to your home country (or country of residence) and that you can afford to support yourself.

Comment: What is your country of citizenship?